# Does NetBeans have automatic code-completion for C++?

Tags: autocomplete, netbeans, ide, c++

Does NetBeans facilitate code-completion for C++? If yes then what are the shortcuts to use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does.

You'll need C++ version of NetBeans or you'll need to download the C/C++ plug-in from plug-ins menu.

I can't remember all shortcuts since I haven't used in some time, but CTRL+SPACE is the one I used used the most.

Once you start typing code, you'll get menus under each keyword you start typing. Arrows and CRTL+SPACE are used to select available options.

Comment: I have installed C++ plugin for NetBeans. but CTRL+SPACE doe something else in Ubuntu. Do you think that there even exists auto-completion feature for C++

Comment: I have used it on Solaris, so I know it is there for sure. I could have misremembered CTRL+SPACE. I'll boot Ubuntu and try it out now.

Comment: @Akhil  It is CTRL+SPACE. Take a look at [this pdf](http://usersguide.netbeans.org/shortcuts.pdf). According to my settings, that key changes keyboard layout in Ubuntu. You could try changing setting so that they do not conflict. Go to tools->options->keymap and type code in the search field. You'll get a list of all code completion settings there.

Comment: I was hoping, that maybe Netbeans will autocomplete automatically after i type first few letters, something that is standard in for example Code Blocks, but no -_-